# How much is cohomotopy dual to homotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

To what degree can we dualize theorems regarding homotopy into theorems about cohomotopy (or is there a good source that tries to do this)?

For instance, is there some kind of Hurewicz theorem relating cohomotopy and ordinary cohomology? Is there a "cohomotopy extension property" (something that applies when relative cohomotopy groups are trivial)? If two spaces are cohomologically equivalent and have some property in cohomotopy analogous to simply-connected, are they cohomotopy equivalent?

Thanks, this is primarily a reference request, however there is the possibility that all this is impossible so no such reference exists, which would also be an acceptable answer.

Comment: There is a result of Hopf: if $X$ is an $n-1$-connected space (say, CW complex), then maps of $X$ into the $n$-sphere are the same as cohomology classes in $H^n(X; \mathbb{Z})$. (You can prove this quickly by noting that the relevant property is true when $S^n$ is replaced by the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$, and that can be obtained from $S^n$ by attaching $n+2$-cells and higher.)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is actually an immensely useful fact, and this result solves the problem that prompted the asking of this question (at least I think it does, I will have to check all the details) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80331/maps-of-wedges-being-nullhomotopic.

Comment: Akhil, do you mean $n-1$ dimensional or something? Or even $n$ dimensional... and then CW approximation. For example, $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ is $n-1$ connected, but certainly it's cohomology is not the same as it's cohomotopy...

Comment: @Dylan: Thanks! I forgot $n$-dimensional, and you're right about the proof.

Comment: @Dylan: And, moreover, I was being very silly -- what I meant was that maps into any $n-1$-connected space from an $n$-dimensional space.

Comment: One potential restriction to some kind of natural duality is that the cohomotopy groups are defined only in the stable range. Or do you mean some stable (co)homotopy groups?

Answer (score 3):

The homotopy groups can be written as covariant homotopy invariant functors $\pi_n:\mathrm{Top}_\ast\to\mathrm{Set}$. If we were to consider contravariant homotopy invariant functors $\pi^n:\mathrm{Top}_\ast^{op}\to\mathrm{Set}$, we would obtain the cohomotopy sets. How dual is it? Well, $\pi^n(S^m)=\pi_m(S^n)$. If $X$ is a CW-complex of dimension (at most) $n$, then $\pi^p(X)\to H^p(X)$ is a bijection. See [the nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohomotopy). As for whether or not a "cohomotopy extension property" exists, I don't know; it seems like an interesting thing!

Answer (score 1):

All homology/cohomology is with integer coefficients.

The Hurewicz map that you are looking is defined as follows I think: Given a homotopy class $f:X\rightarrow S^n$, and $[u]\in H^n(S^n)$ you get $f^*[u]\in H^n[X]$. If you take now $[u]$ to be the positive generator of $H^n(S^n)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ you get a nice map $h:\pi^n\rightarrow H^n(X)$.

If $X$ is an $n$-dimensional CW complex any map into an $n+k$-connected space (e.g. n+k dim sphere) is homotopically trivial. Combining this with the observation that $pi^n\cong H^n(X)$ for $n$-dimensional closed manifolds we see that $\pi^l(X)\cong H^l(X)$ for all $l\geq n$ for $n$ dimensional closed manifolds. Furthermore $\pi^0(X)$ measures the number of connected components of $X$ and as $S^1$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z},1)$ we have that $\pi^1(X)\cong H^1(X)$.