# In what sense is cohomotopy dual to homotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I understand the duality in the case of homology and de Rham cohomology. Through integration a chain can be understood as a linear functional on differential forms and vice versa.

Is there a way to understand cohomotopy classes as functionals on a homotopy group? Is there a different sense in which it is dual?

I am aware of a [similarly titled question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80370/how-much-is-cohomotopy-dual-to-homotopy) but that was more about relating cohomotopy to cohomology rather than to homotopy.

Comment: The cohomotopy set $\pi^n(X)$ is in general not even a group for $n \ge 2$, so it's going to be a weird kind of duality if it exists... Are you talking about stable cohomotopy?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of deeper duality than the fact that the homotopy groups are defined by $\pi_n(X)=[S^n,X]$ and the cohomotopy by $\pi^n(X)=[X,S^n]$?

Comment: @DanielRust, Yes (unless I'm misunderstanding your notation) I was hoping there was something deeper behind the name. Like a way to say something about cohomotopy through the structure of $\pi_n$ itself, rather than having to refer back to $X$, or something of that sort.